# Shortest Windows batch file code to get first line of a file set to a variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am looking for the shortest amount of code possible that will get the first line of a text file and set it to a variable in Windows.

There are lots of examples of this kind of thing in other threads on this StackExchange site but I am **not** looking for how to loop through and display all lines in a file.  What I want is to just **simply** get the first line.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
set /p var= <Text.txt
echo %var%
```

Referenced from: http://forums.techguy.org/software-development/551867-batch-file-read-line-text.html
Ironically the poster is able to get the first line but wanted to loop through the whole file!

Comment: works well, but you should delete the space between the = and the < otherwise your variable has a space as first character: (This is how it should look like: **set /p var=<Text.txt** )

Comment: I just tried what you suggested vs what's in the answer and there is no difference running it on win7. The only way I can get spaces is by actually putting it into the Text.txt file. Have you tested your suggestion?

Comment: It gets only the first line of the file

Comment: @Daniel, please re-read the question, especially the part of the first sentence that mentions "first line of the file"

Comment: Yeah, but by removing the space, its closer to my request for "shortest possible" way, right?

Comment: yes, you're right and going with the flow here, u can also shave off 2 chars from having a single char variable ;)

Comment: aware this is late, but no need for the space before the slash

Comment: Please note: Using the approach will only read the first 1k bytes. If the line is < 1K, this approach is fine, but be aware of the limitation. As a partial reference, see [batch variable character limit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21723275)

Answer (score 18):

This is just a slightly shorter version:

```bat
set/pz=<file
echo %z%
```

Comment: Yes, I verified it. It works perfectly by removing the 2 spaces.  Nice answer.  I suppose it deserves the green checkmark but since this is almost 3 years later, I am not going to.  I just hope people give you up-marks to recognize your contribution.

Comment: thank you for verifying it. i hope that it could help someone someday, so i posted it.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get this to work under Windows 7; the variable was simply not set. But here's a slightly longer solution:

```bat
for /F "delims=" %%i in (Text.txt) do (  
  set Z=%%i
  goto BREAK1
)
:BREAK1
echo %Z%
```

Comment: This fails when the first line is empty or begins with a `;` and it's tricky to handle when delayed expansion is enabled

Answer (score 2):

If [delayed expansion](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060823-00/?p=29993) has been enabled before (`Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` or cmd started with `/V:ON` option) then there's a shorter (one-liner) version

```bat
set /pz=<filename.txt&echo !z!
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the line of file for a text file inside `Program Files(x86)` directory. After trying a lot of solutions, the following solution worked for me:

Steps:

1. Use `type` command piped with `findstr`to get a file with the desired data
2. Delete the original file
3. Use `type` command to move the content back to the file with the original file name
4. Delete the new file

Example:

```
@echo off
set originalFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\<Target File Path>\<Target File Name>"
set newFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\<Target File Path>\<Target newFile Name>"
if exist %originalFile% (
    type %originalFile% | findstr /v T4VSHost >> %newFile%
    del %originalFile% /F /Q
    type %newFile% >> %originalFile%
    del %newFile% /F /Q
)
@echo on
```

**Note:**

When I tried writing the change back to the original file in step 1, the result was a an empty file.

Note the string I am matching is `T4VSHost`, which occurs in the file at path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude`

Comment: That's because of different encodings. type recodes Unicode to ANSI. (batch can only handle ANSI; has problems with Unicode)

Answer (score -1):

just FYI...

I tried it and didn't work. But I realized finally that I had to reproduce the text file (originally the text file is generated by a powershell script) so when I did this and it works.

```bat
:: output to different file
Type Text.txt > text2.txt
```

Then apply the same code (change `text.txt` to `text2.txt`)

```bat
set /p var= <Text2.txt
echo %var%
```

If I use the original one, I would either get garbage in `%var%`, not sure if the text file has not `<CR>` or what.  Anyway, by reproducing the text file, it seems working fine.

Comment: That's because of different encodings. `type` recodes Unicode to ANSI. (batch can only handle ANSI; has problems with Unicode, whereas Powershell can handle both (there should be a switch or cmdlet to convert to ANSI)