# How to override batch variable number of characters limit?

Tags: variables, batch-file, character, limit

I'm having an issue on the current project I'm working on.
I have to get a query stored from a file into a variable, whose file only contains a query (It is generated by part of the program). For instance I use the following code:

```
set /p query=<path\to\my\folder\fileContainingQuery.soql
```

It works when the query isn't that long, but when its length is beyond 1024 characters, the query is truncated and since I gotta send it to another configuration file using the FART tool, that's quite not convenient.

How to override this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a limit in how many data can be stored in a environment variable. In theory, the maximum length is 32767 characters, BUT a batch file cannot set a variable that is longer than the maximum command line length (8192).

You can use a `for /f` command to read the line

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in ("path\to\my\folder\fileContainingQuery.soql") do set "q=%%f"
```

Or you can generate a auxiliary batch file to assign the content of the query

```
<nul set/px=set q=>sql.set.cmd
type "path\to\my\folder\fileContainingQuery.soql">>sql.set.cmd
call sql.set.cmd
```

And both will get the maximum possible text into the variable ONLY if the final command line is not too big (8186 characters in my tests). In other case, nothing is retrieved.

BUT, once the value has been retrieved, is has to be used inside a command. And here the same limitation happens. 8192 is the maximum line length and the content of the variable IS inside the line.

So, your final limit for the length of the query is less than that.

Comment: 8191 Bytes is the maximum length of the CMD line buffer.  The extra byte is reserved. (Note, this seems to be a hold-over from the 16 bit versions of the operating system, as this is a match for the 16 bit integer max of 65536 values 0 to 65535 with 8 reserved bits.)

Comment: You can check for yourself by directly pasting a glob of characters into the command line, and you will find that it truncates at exactly 8191 characters every time.

Comment: The reserved character is needed for entering a control character so the register can only accept those characters such as EOL.

Comment: In any case, if you SET a variable, or ECHO a Variable, that text for the command counts as part of the line length, and, so practically, you are limited to setting or displaying a variable to exactly 8186 (8191-5) characters, as you need a minimum of exactly 5 characters to do either a SET or ECHO command.

Comment: using a little thinking on this though, and I did find a way to set and display one extra character in a variable, to reach a total of 8187 characters in a variable.  You can store "SET A=" in a Variable, say "s" `SET "s=SET A="`, and then use that to set the line, allowing more characters on the line to be interpreted. But even though you can write three more characters, only the one extra character is shown.

Comment: Furthermore, if you do the same trick with ECHO, you can display two extra characters (even though you can write three more)

Comment: So for Variables you can make a max of 8187 characters usably, but only if you store the SET command inside a single character variable.

Comment: Also, please note that echo.%Variable% will always echo the entire contents of the variable to the line, I was only noting that you can enter more characters towards the line max by holding echo inside a variable if you are writing a literal string to echo.

Comment: @BenPersonick, CMD command line buffer is a null (`\x00` ) terminated buffer defined with a size of 8KB (8192). The terminator requirement limits the command line to 8191 usable characters. You are right in the 8187 limit with `echo` (I had to use `call %s%` with `s=echo %^x^%`). I'm not sure what you mean with the *"`echo.%variable%` always echo the entire contents of the variable"*

Comment: Thanks for confirming my assertion that the line buffer can only accept 8191 printable characters, and the max variable size allowing 8187 characters.  Since you are in a loop you will need to use Call or use a cmd script to enable delayed expansion to generate the set and echo.  Outside of a loop, or with delayed expansion in a cmd script the call isn't necessary.

Comment: As for the comment about the echo, I seem to have deleted and not put back some of the content that was in that comment.  I was saying that, when testing for max characters ecoable, I reached 8188, and that even though you can store the "echo." in a variable to get around the buffer limit of characters you can enter on a line, it will not allow more than 8188 characters before sending "This line too Long" errors.

Comment: So, when you have already stored the 8187 characters in a variable, instead of on the screen, I was still able to use ECHO. and print 8188 characters, even though e expanded line is over 8188 characters.  This indicates that it is not necessary to store "echo." as a variable the same way it is required to store "SET A=" as a variable as long as the content to echo is stored in variables even when wanting to print 8188 characters.  Only when directly echoing a literal tied string of 8188 characters is the echo requires to be stored in a variable in order for the buffer to handle it correctly.

Comment: I will add an answer just so I can explain this more clearly.

Comment: @benpersonick, out of a loop, with a 8187 character variable , on my system with or without the echo in a variable I get a line too long error. I had to use the call to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

@MC ND: Thanks for your answer, I used the `for /f` command this way after thinking back at it. (Didn't read your answer at this moment).

```
(for /f "delims=" %%b in (path\to\my\folder\fileContainingQuery.soql) do (
    set query=%%b
))
echo %query%
```

My hypothesis for my previous problem is that the set /p var function may only accept 1024 characters on user input, and as my query file only contains one line which length could be greater than this limit, it truncates the query. The above code works fine for me and I get my complete query in the variable.