# MS-DOS Pipe the content of a file into a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to send the content of a text file (which is just one word) into a variable in MS-DOS.

I tried doing it with pipes like so ,without any success

```
TYPE username.txt | %savedName%
```

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Do you actually mean MS-DOS or do you mean a Windows command line?

Comment: I'm trying to do it in a batch file, which I'm pretty sure is in ms-dos, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: If you are using a computer from 20+ years ago, then you mean MS-DOS.  I'm guessing you're actually using the command line on a more modern Windows computer, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shortest DOS batch file code to get first line of a file set to a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023545/shortest-dos-batch-file-code-to-get-first-line-of-a-file-set-to-a-variable)

Comment: I did take a look at that, but the code doesn't seem to be working. I tried set /p savedName=< username.txt

Comment: The word has to be on the first line of the text file - it does work.

Comment: Are you saying the code on the page is working, or mine?

Comment: I was replying to your comment above mine

Answer (score 4):

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (username.txt) do set "savedname=%%i"
echo savedname=%savedname%
```

should work for you (as a batch file). If you are executing directly from the prompt, then reduce each `%%` to `%`.

If you are nunning this on a Windows machine using WIN NT4, Win2000, WINXP, WIN7, Vista or Win8 then this should work (as also the `set/p` approach should have worked)

If you are using Win95, Win98, WinME or real MSDOS, then a different approach would be required.

"MSDOS" is often used to mean "Command Prompt" - a generic term ridiculously misapplied to mean "A windows application which emulates the functionality of the MSDOS command-interpreter (with enhanced functionality)". Unfortunately, since "AWAWETFOTMCI(WEF)" is such a mouthful, many people abbreviate it to "MSDOS" or "DOS". This raises the ire of that sad section of the computing community that is more interested in asserting that MSDOS no longer exists than in communicating effectively.

Comment: I don't understand your closing comment Magoo - MSdos certainly exists and some people use it.  To give effective support in a question, you have to know if they are using MSdos or Windows, when their question and code doesn't show which it is.

Comment: @foxidrive: Certainly. I haven't turned my Kaypro PC10 on in more than a year, and it was still running MSDOS6.22 when I last used it. Similarly, my homebrew Lantastic server - the one with the 1.45Gb HDD. For that matter, I've not activated any of my Win98 machines in that time either. All have some version of genuine MSDOS - W9x is simply a MSDOS app loaded by default. Apparently, the manufacturer is no longer willing to sell new licences, and its sycophants thus claim MSDOS no longer exists. Clearly, the functionality is still there and hence it exists by duck-typing.

Comment: @Magoo: I am with you. I used to write "MS-DOS" when I referred to Batch file questions, but after some angry replies I now use Windows/DOS Batch files. In my opinion, "MSDOS" should be understand as "Windows/DOS command-line - Batch files". If a user have a "MS-DOS specific question", he/she should note this particular point in the question...

Comment: @Aacini The problem there is that most people don't know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

this one is working fine and simpler

```
set /p SCHEMAS=<schemas_file.txt
```